# The present perfect tense describing a future event?

Tags: present-perfect, future-tense

I was working out an online Enlish test, and came up into this question:

> I'll get in touch with you as soon as I _____ the results.
>
> Your Answer: *am informed to*
>
> Correct: **have been informed of**

The event of "informing" is happening in the future (unknown time), I know that simple present is inaccurate, but how the present perfect tense can be used in this context?

Comment: Who says you can not use simple present after as soon as? You can use both simple present and present perfect.

Comment: so both are correct?

Comment: Your answer is acceptable except that ‘informed’ should always be used with ‘of’ or ‘that’ (not in this situation though) and not ‘to’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both simple present and present perfect. The meaning is almost the same. However, using **present perfect** sounds better in this sentence.

Using present perfect means you will get in touch with him/her once you are **completely** informed (you have **complete** information about results), and using simple present means you will get in touch with him/her whenever you have **a piece (or pieces) of information** about results (maybe you are **not completely** informed and you may provide a rapid response).

Comment: But why ignoring the fact that this is a future event? is there examples of using both tenses in a future sentence, where they fit the context?

Comment: I know (by common sense) that using 'will' out the alike is not correct.

Comment: According to “The Cambridge Grammar Of the English Language”:
*“Time- adjuncts and the complements of temporal prepositions such as:
as soon as, etc., take the simple present, not the will- construction, when the reference is to future time."* It's somehow like using "will" in an if-clause. We are not allowed to use will in an if clause, but there are exceptions to the rule. OK, I will find examples from valid references for you.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/as+soon+as) example from "The Free Dictionary": *As soon as we get the tickets we'll send them to you.* or this one from "English Grammar in Use" p. 50: *You'll feel better after you've had something to eat.*